# What do I do if the information on the main website isn't true?

Tags: discussion, support, tag-wiki

I noticed that the tag description for Python is not completely accurate; it claims Python is strongly typed. Python is very much *not* strongly typed! Anyhow, I am not necessarily a high rep user, certainly not high enough to change things like this. So my question is: what should you do if you don't have enough rep to change false information? Is there a way to ***request*** a change of a question or tag or, well, anything you are not "qualified" to change? If not, this is something to keep in mind...

Comment: It is all just a definition, but [wikipedia states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29#Typing): `Python is strongly typed, forbidding operations that are not well-defined [...] rather than silently attempting to make sense of them`

Comment: Uhm, Python is **definitely** strongly typed. It's objects have one type and are not coerced into other types; summing an integer to a string doesn't coerce the string or integer into the other type.

Comment: You are getting confusing *strong and weak* typing and *dynamic and static* typing. Python is dynamically typed as the variables carry no type information, it is the objects they reference that carry this. The opposite of *strong* typing is *weak* typing; JavaScript and Perl are weakly typed in that the value types can change easily depending on context.

Comment: See [Is Python strongly typed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11328920)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I see... I suppose I should have done a little more research before asking...I learned something new today! I thought I was told by a veteran Python user that Python is strongly typed, but he may have said dynamically typed, and confused them, just like you said. thanks !

Answer (score 5):

You can suggest an edit to the tag wiki, but please ensure that you describe your edit properly in the "Edit summary". It helps reviewers to understand why you suggested the edit.

Collaborative editing is the strength of this site. One can suggest edits if they have less rep.

To edit a tag wiki, [open the tag and select "Improve tag wiki"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python). To view your suggested edit (and see if it got approved or rejected) go to your profile page, [select the "All actions" tab and open "revisions".](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4254754/oboy?tab=activity&sort=revisions)

---

**Note:** In case of wiki's for high traffic tags (such as python) and/or for wikis which have multiple editors, posting on Meta first is advisable.

Comment: Except that the tag wiki isn't incorrect; the change the OP suggests should be roundly rejected.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: that's what reviewing is for. The *procedure* as described is the correct one.

Comment: @Jongware: sure, but I am sceptical reviewers would actually spot the change being factually wrong. I've seen too many incorrect edit suggestions go through (including complete copyrighted texts copied and pasted into tag wikis), to fully trust that process.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But what are you suggesting? It's no good to tell someone "But don't edit if you're wrong" - clearly they wouldn't be editing if they didn't think they were right.

Comment: @sphanley you stated the right procedure, yes. I guess my caveat is: *but do your research first to make sure you understand the concepts.*

Answer (score 0):

Certainly. Post here, providing a link to what you think is inaccurate, explain why you think that is the case, and provide an explanation of what the appropriate content should be. ("Not true" is a little harsh - perhaps a little more appropriate would be "I think is incorrect".)

Comment: thank you, I learned something today! and yes, that might have been a little harsh, thank you for the feedback.